# Track Lighting Issue

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I recently installed track lighting, and upon turning on the power switch, none of the lights turned on. I went back, checked all of my connections, tested the power, checked each lightbulb, but that was to no avail. Each socket is getting electricity and all of the bulbs work, but the fixture won't turn on. Any ideas?

Comment: I know with "some" track lighting *it matters* which  way you twist them in. Which ever way you tried, try it again from the opposite direction. There are slots up in the tracks that must line up with the light

Answer (score 1):

If there is power to the sockets and the bulbs are good, then it is a "bulb-to-socket" problem.

Are you sure the bulbs are inserted such that they are making proper contact? Sometimes fixture housings prevent some bulbs from inserting all the way. In fact, I have some fixtures that require special 'long neck" bulbs...

Comment: Well, that would make sense, but... The track lighting kit came with both the bulbs and the housing. On top of that, the kit came with three track lights, and I purchased an extra one (same company, model and compatible with the track light kit), so I would find it odd that all four fixtures are having "bulb-to-socket" problems.

Answer (score 1):

I know with "some" track lighting it matters which way you twist them in. Which ever way you tried, try it again from the opposite direction. There are slots up in the tracks that must line up with the light

Comment: There were certain plastic pieces that had to line up along a groove in the track, and when you look at the picture, I installed in the same way.

Comment: I've seen where they can be put in backwards and that is usually the case. Of one is certain there's power, certain they've put them in correctly, and one has put in more than one ( the right way ) them it's time to measure voltage at the track itself and then take out each fixture, do a continuity ( ohm ) test between the lighting fixture stabs and the bulb socket connections. I would definitely try those bulbs elsewhere in the house to see if they light...

Comment: That's one of the first things I did: tried each bulb individually.